# spring @sqlgroup with multiple datasource

Tags: spring-test

I am trying to use @sql and @sqlgroup on my unit test but I want this annotation to  use datasource with different name other than default datasource.

How can you achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Transaction management for @Sql](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-executing-sql-declaratively-tx) section of the Spring Reference Manual:

> If the algorithms used by `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener` to detect a
>   `DataSource` and `PlatformTransactionManager` and infer the transaction
>   semantics do not suit your needs, you may specify explicit names via
>   the `dataSource` and `transactionManager` attributes of `@SqlConfig`.

For example:

```java
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql(scripts = "script1.sql", config = @SqlConfig(dataSource = "dataSource1", transactionManager = "txMgr1")),
    @Sql(scripts = "script2.sql", config = @SqlConfig(dataSource = "dataSource2", transactionManager = "txMgr2"))
})
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Sorry for necromancing this, but I had the same issue and tried your solution. For some reason, it only uses the data source of the first \@Sql correctly. I have the \@SqlGroup at class declaration, it runs both scripts, but the first at the beggining of the class, and persists throughout every test, but it tries to run the second script at every test, creating primary key errors (by trying to insert the same). If I swicth the order, it does the same for the new second script as well.

Comment: @EBM I'm having a difficult time following your exact setup. Would you mind creating a JIRA issue with more details? https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Comment: Here's the issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-149 Thank you.

Comment: Got it. Wrong project... but I fixed that. ;-) I'll try to take a look into it soon.